# Opencart sort by manufacturer in Category pages

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by, opencart

Ok, I would like to add one more sort variable on category pages, that is to sort by Manufacturer.
Running on 1.5.3.1 and have tried this:
1. catalog/controller/product/category.php
added the following:

```
$this->data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_manufacturer_asc'),
            'value' => 'manufacturer-ASC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=manufacturer&order=ASC' . $url)
        );

$this->data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_manufacturer_desc'),
                'value' => 'manufacturer-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=manufacturer&order=DESC' . $url)
            );
```

1. catalog/language/*/product/category.php
   added:

   $_['text_manufacturer_asc']    = '▲ -Proizvođaču- ▲';
   $_['text_manufacturer_desc']   = '▼ -Proizvođaču- ▼';
2. catalog/model/catalog/product.php
   before: 'p.date_added' I inserted a line:

   'manufacturer'

and few lines below I changed the block with the following one:

```
    if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
    if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
    } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
    } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'manufacturer') {
        $sql .= " SELECT * FROM". DB_PREFIX . "product p ORDER BY manufacturer";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
    }
} else {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";   
}
```

But it is not working.
Error says:

```
PHP Notice:  Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROMproduct p ORDER BY manufacturer ASC,...
```

and another one I have found:

```
PHP Notice:  Error: Unknown column 'special' in 'order clause'<br />Error No: 1054<br />SELECT p.product_id, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id)...
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there but You will have to modify it a little bit more.

First, You really do not want to order by manufacturer ID stored in `product.manufacturer_id` **but by manufacturer name**. In this case we need to modify the query in `catalog\model\catalog\product.php` model in `getProducts` method - find this line:

```php
$sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'";
```

(should be line **89** in OC 1.5.5.1) and **before** it add:

```php
$sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id";
```

Also You'll need to allow manufacturer as a sorting option:

```php
$sort_data = array(
    'pd.name',
    'p.model',
    'p.quantity',
    'p.price',
    'rating',
    'p.sort_order',
    'p.date_added',
    'manufacturer', // <== this is added
);
```

Now in the sorting section add sorting by manufacturer name:

```php
if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
    if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
    } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
    } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'manufacturer') { // <== this is added
        $sql .= " ORDER BY m.name";              // <== this is added
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
    }
} else {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";   
}
```

And that's it.

Comment: thanks for your help. now no error, but it sorts by default. I am making a vqmod for this change so I have found only now that I am missing the line you quoted to be on 89 of OC 1.5.5.1... There is no such line in 1.5.3.1 - it seems.

Comment: Then You will need to find the place where to put this new line. It has to be somewhere between `LEFT JOIN`s and `WHERE` clause... It there is no such space in between to fill with that line, then pick the SQL and place it inside the main SQL part that is getting the products (I believe You understand SQL syntax and clauses).

Comment: ok, vqmod is not making changes in catalog/model/catalog/product.php file so I did change it manualy. there is an error now saying that: PHP Notice:  Error: Unknown column 'm.name' in 'order clause

Comment: I have changed it from m.name to name and it is working but sorting not by manufacturer, not by default... I do not know how it is sorting.